# ruby inheritance

Tags: ruby, inheritance

How to implement inheritance in ruby for the following?

```
class Land
  attr_accessor :name, :area
  def initialize(name, area)
    @name = name
    @area = area
  end
end

class Forest < Land
  attr_accessor :rain_level
  attr_reader :name

  def name=(_name)
    begin
      raise "could not set name"
    rescue  Exception => e
            puts e.message  
        end
  end

  def initialize(land, rain_level)
    @name = land.name
    @rain_level = rain_level
  end
end

l = Land.new("land", 2300)
f = Forest.new(l, 400)
puts f.name # => "land"
```

suppose when i change name for land l, then it should change for sub class also

```
l.name ="new land"
puts f.name # => "land"
```

what expected is  puts f.name # => "new land"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of an interesting thing you want to build.

Summarizing you want to have two objects that share a value but only one is allowed to edit the value, the other one is only allowed to read it.

I think the easiest way to implement this is in your case to implement a new getter in Forest which returns `land.name`. By writing `l.name = 'meow'` will `f.name` return `moew` too because it holds a reference to `l`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this is not actually inheritance in the OO sense. If you change `Forest` so that it holds a reference to the `Land` then you will get the behavior you wanted.

```
class Forest
  attr_accessor :rain_level

  def name
    @land.name
  end

  def initialize(land, rain_level)
    @land = land
    @rain_level = rain_level
  end
end
```

Comment: yes, it can achieved without inheritance. How can approach it in inheritance way?. like father can set and get value and son only get the value

Comment: Inheritance just doesn't work that way. If you shave the mustache of your father it doesn't mean that your upper lip will also be shaved.

Comment: i understand, i expect something like if my father changes his address then my address should change automatically. If my expectation is not a kind of inheritance then please ignore it.

Comment: "For example, consider a class Person that contains a person's name, address, phone number, age, gender, and race. We can define a subclass of Person called Student that contains the person's grade point average and classes taken, and another subclass of Person called Employee that contains the person's job-title, employer, and salary." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(computer_science)